# How to do a request using AuthHttp JWT Token in Angular 4 to a Spring Boot API mapped with @RequestPart?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, angular2-jwt

I hava a Rest API developmented in Java using Spring boot. And it provides a resource mapped with @RequestPart that I receive an File and another content to pass to a service. Until now, all right. I can test in Postman no problems.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/content")
public class ContentResource {

private ContentService conteudoService;

@Autowired
public ContentResource(ContentService contentService) {
    this.contentService= contentService;
}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Content> publicaContent(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart String content ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    Content convertedContent = new ObjectMapper().readValue(content , Content.class);
    Content storagedContent = contentService.uploadContent(convertedContent, file);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(storagedContent );
}
```

So, I need to do a request from my Angular 4 application, using AuthHttp of the JWT. How I could do it ?

Follows an example of other service I've implemented using JWT.

```
@Injectable()
export class StudentService {

url = 'localhost:8080/api/student';

constructor(
   private http: AuthHttp
) { }

save(student: Student): Promise<any> {
return this.http.post(this.url, student)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json());
}
}
```

Comment: JWT is passed in HTTP "Bearer" header and is validated by Spring using their HTTP security configuration. This can be a good start: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

Comment: @tsolakp thank you for your answer. I think that I could not explain very well. The problem is how I will to send the File and the content together in POST. In the resource, it has two RequestParts and I do not know how to pass.